# Decimal validation in the textfield using javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i Want to validate a text field in **keyup** event .

in the field it should accept money type decimal like

(12.23)
(.23)
(0.26)
(5.09)
(6.00)

if i enter some wrong value then it should return to the previous value and remove the wrong one

Comment: Thats your requirement, what have you tried so far?  I would be easy for us to point out the mistake if you show us the code.

Comment: @abiansh what does it mean when you say "it should return to the previous value"

Comment: var theEvent = evt || window.event;
    var key = theEvent.keyCode || theEvent.which;
    key = String.fromCharCode(key);
    var regex = /^(\d{0,2})(\.\d{2})$/; // number with 2 decimal places
    if (!regex.test(key)) {
        theEvent.returnValue = false;
        //--- this prevents the character from being displayed
        if (theEvent.preventDefault) theEvent.preventDefault();
    }

Answer (score 4):

I think something like this might be your best bet

```
var isValidCurrency = function(str) {
  var num = parseFloat(str);
  return !Number.isNaN(num) && num.toFixed(2).toString() === str;
};
```

Some tests

```
isValidCurrency("1234.56");   // true
isValidCurrency("1234.565");  // false
isValidCurrency("1234");      // false
isValidCurrency("foo");       // false
```

Comment: Doesn't work for the edge case "00.00"

Comment: I would argue that more than one leading zero is not valid.

Comment: @T.G, "123foo" is not a valid currency. `isValidCurrency("123foo")` returns `false` which is appropriate in this case.

Comment: @T.G if you want, you can delete your comments and I'll delete mine to avoid confusion for other users.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function evMoneyFormat(evt) {
    //--- only accepts accepts number and 2 decimal place value
    var theEvent = evt || window.event;
    var key = theEvent.keyCode || theEvent.which;
    key = String.fromCharCode(key);
    var regex = /^[0-9]{1,14}\.[0-9]{0,2}$/; // number with 2 decimal places
    if (!regex.test(key)) {
        theEvent.returnValue = false;
        //--- this prevents the character from being displayed
        if (theEvent.preventDefault) theEvent.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

The control:

```
<input type='text' onkeyup='evMoneyFormat( e );'>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use following Regex

```
val = "2.13"
if (!val.match(/^(\d{0,2})(\.\d{2})$/)) {
    alert("wrong");
} else {
    alert("right");
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rtL3J/1/

**EDIT**

Please note that if the numbers preceding dot (.) has limit of length to two then the code valid code is

```
^(\d{0,2})(\.\d{2})$
```

else if there is no limit then just remove the `2` from the code i.e.

```
^(\d{0,})(\.\d{2})$
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following code

```
function validateDecimal(num){

   var dotPosition=num.indexOf(".");

   if(dotPosition=="-1"){
      document.getElementById('cost').value= num+".00"
   }
}
```

And in html

```
<input type="text" id='cost' onkeyup="validateDecimal(this.value)" />
```

Comment: You are multiplying number by hundred? need to add `.` before `00`.